# Solution for quadratic returns wrong imaginary solutions when the discriminant is negative

Tags: java, math, quadratic

I am trying to get into programming more, and this is one thing that a friend recommended that I do. I'm trying to write a quadratic solver, but it is giving the wrong answer, however neither of us can figure out why.

We are using this equation as an example: x^2+4x+5 = 0 
The solutions for it are x=-2+1 and x=-2-i
The eclipse console reads this:

```
Quadratic equation: 
Please enter A: 
1
Please enter B: 
4
Please enter C: 
5
Your first solution is: -3.0
Your second solution is: -5.0
```

Here is the code being used:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Quadratic equation: ");
        System.out.println("Please enter A: ");

        while(!input.hasNextInt()){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String broken = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter A: ");
        }

        int a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter B: ");

        while(!input.hasNextInt()){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String broken = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter B: ");
        }

        int b = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter C: ");

        while(!input.hasNextInt()){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String broken = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter C: ");
        }

        int c = input.nextInt();

        double imaginaryCheck = (b*b)-(4*a*c);

        if(imaginaryCheck>0){
            double plus = (-b) + Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck) / (2 * a);
            double minus = (-b) - Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck) / (2 * a);
            System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2f\n", plus);
            System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2f", minus); 
        }else{
            double plus = (-b) + Math.sqrt((-1*imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
            double minus = (-b) - Math.sqrt((-1*imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2fi\n", plus);
            System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2fi", minus); 
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an error somewhere or did I mess up the equation somehow?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you tell?

Comment: your imaginary part is off - that is not how the calculation works

Comment: Your solution would only print either entirely real or entirely imaginary cases. Typically you would get a complex root (i.e. with both a real part and an imaginary part) rather than a purely imaginary one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should probably include a case for `imaginaryCheck==0` because in that case you only get one solution.
2. You always forget the parentheses for the part over the fraction making the actual formula you use wrong
3. The biggest problem: your imaginary solution calculation is wrong. That is not how the calculation of the imaginary values work.

The correct one should somewhat look like this:

```
double plusReal = (-b) / (double)(2 * a);
double minusReal = (-b) / (double)(2 * a);

double plusImaginary = Math.sqrt(-1 * imaginaryCheck) / (2 * a);
double minusImaginary = -Math.sqrt(-1 * imaginaryCheck) / (2 * a);

System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2f + %1.2fi\n", plusReal, plusImaginary);
System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2f + %1.2fi", minusReal, minusImaginary);
```

You have to calculate the real part and the imaginary part separately - you cannot just simply sum them up. That will correctly output:

> Your first solution is: -2.00 + 1.00i
>   Your second solution is: -2.00 + -1.00i

The `if`-branch should look like the following with corrected parentheses:

```
double plus = ((-b) + Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
double minus = ((-b) - Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2f\n", plus);
System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2f", minus);
```

The code should finally look like

```
if (imaginaryCheck > 0) {
    double plus = (-b + Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
    double minus = (-b - Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);

    System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2f\n", plus);
    System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2f", minus);
} else if (imaginaryCheck == 0) {
    double plus = -b / (double) (2 * a);

    System.out.format("Your only solution is: %1.2f\n", plus);
} else {
    double plusReal = -b / (double) (2 * a);
    double plusImaginary = Math.sqrt(-1 * imaginaryCheck) / (2 * a);

    System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2f + %1.2fi\n", plusReal, plusImaginary);
    System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2f - %1.2fi", plusReal, plusImaginary);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect a response this quickly, nor one this thorough.

Comment: @CorruptComputer you are welcome, that was fun :) Note that I have simplified the imaginary calculation a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the calculations to:

```
    if(imaginaryCheck>0){
        double plus = ((-b) + Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
        double minus = ((-b) - Math.sqrt(imaginaryCheck)) / (2 * a);
        System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2f\n", plus);
        System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2f", minus); 
    }else{
        double plus = ((-b) + Math.sqrt((-1*imaginaryCheck))) / (2 * a);
        double minus = ((-b) - Math.sqrt((-1*imaginaryCheck))) / (2 * a);
        System.out.format("Your first solution is: %1.2fi\n", plus);
        System.out.format("Your second solution is: %1.2fi", minus); 
    }
```

Reason: Because * and / operators have higher precedence than + and -. Refer to [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for more details

Assumption: Your calculation of imaginary part is correct i.e %1.2fi. If not sure about the calculation itself, then luk2302 solution to find imaginary solution would work.